# Can't change tableview frame

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uicollectionview

I just want to change tableview frame in viewwillappear with [easyPeasy](https://github.com/nakiostudio/EasyPeasy/) for autolayout.

I have collectionview and tableview in one viewcontroller.I'm using both of them.But in the first open I'm hiding collectionview and trying to move tableview y point to 0.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.collectionView.hidden = true
        self.tableView <- [
            Top(0).to((self.navigationController?.navigationBar)!, .Bottom)
        ]
    }
```

And it's giving me this error.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c06f370 UIImageView:0x14c1c2d30.width == 40>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c1e5ff0 UIImageView:0x14c1c2d30.width == 22>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c06f370 UIImageView:0x14c1c2d30.width == 40>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
nil
2016-08-29 01:06:37.034 Bons[985:280487] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c0e29d0 UIImageView:0x14c1e9ee0.width == 40>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c1e7f00 UIImageView:0x14c1e9ee0.width == 22>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c0e29d0 UIImageView:0x14c1e9ee0.width == 40>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
nil
2016-08-29 01:06:37.044 Bons[985:280487] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c0f5c50 UIImageView:0x14c0f4a10.width == 40>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c1e7fc0 UIImageView:0x14c0f4a10.width == 22>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c0f5c50 UIImageView:0x14c0f4a10.width == 40>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
nil
2016-08-29 01:06:37.053 Bons[985:280487] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c0f5930 UILabel:0x14c0f5020.centerY == UITableViewCellContentView:0x14c0f3c60.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c0f59d0 UIImageView:0x14c0f4a10.top == UIImageView:0x14c0f5600.top + 5>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c0f5a70 UIImageView:0x14c0f4a10.centerY == UILabel:0x14c0f5020.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c0f5b10 UITableViewCellContentView:0x14c0f3c60.bottomMargin == UIImageView:0x14c0f5600.bottom - 1>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c0f5bb0 UIImageView:0x14c0f5600.height == 38>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c1f5330 UIImageView:0x14c0f4a10.height == 22>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c1f4cc0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x14c0f3c60.height == 54>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c0f5bb0 UIImageView:0x14c0f5600.height == 38>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-29 01:06:37.062 Bons[985:280487] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c0efad0 UILabel:0x14c0f07b0.centerY == UITableViewCellContentView:0x14c1e85d0.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c0e25a0 UIImageView:0x14c1e9ee0.top == UIImageView:0x14c0ef890.top + 5>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c0e2640 UIImageView:0x14c1e9ee0.centerY == UILabel:0x14c0f07b0.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c0e2890 UITableViewCellContentView:0x14c1e85d0.bottomMargin == UIImageView:0x14c0ef890.bottom - 1>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c0e2930 UIImageView:0x14c0ef890.height == 38>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c0f1c90 UIImageView:0x14c1e9ee0.height == 22>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c1f87a0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x14c1e85d0.height == 54>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c0e2930 UIImageView:0x14c0ef890.height == 38>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-08-29 01:06:37.070 Bons[985:280487] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c089ce0 UILabel:0x14c0c8050.centerY == UITableViewCellContentView:0x14c06e390.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c089d80 UIImageView:0x14c1c2d30.top == UIImageView:0x14c071f20.top + 5>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c089e20 UIImageView:0x14c1c2d30.centerY == UILabel:0x14c0c8050.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c06f230 UITableViewCellContentView:0x14c06e390.bottomMargin == UIImageView:0x14c071f20.bottom - 1>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c06f2d0 UIImageView:0x14c071f20.height == 38>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c1e5560 UIImageView:0x14c1c2d30.height == 22>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c211d80 UITableViewCellContentView:0x14c06e390.height == 54>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14c06f2d0 UIImageView:0x14c071f20.height == 38>
```

Comment: Any third-party library is a two-edged sword. Some things become easier, others more difficult. Debugging stuff which doesn't work is often very painful. My advice is that if the documentation for the library doesn't help you, then ditch the library and use the native Apple API for creating and editing your constraints.

Comment: I didn't use 3rd party framework and tried again.It Failed. Gave me same output

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to establish the relationship between items not contained in the same view. Instead you can:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.collectionView.hidden = true
    self.tableView <- [
        Top(0).to(self.topLayoutGuide))
    ]
}
```